# Sub Query Case Statement Different Values Then Where Clause

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I have a query that i've written two ways 1)with a where clause in the main query and then one with a case statement in the sub query. I am getting slightly (<1%) difference here and was hoping that someone could provide insight?

1) Is there an issue with my code?
2) Is there a difference between how this is aggregated based on where my statement is?

Code #1: Sub Query and With Group By in Sub Query

```
select Type,sum(a.product)                                  
from 
(select a.line, case when c.ID='XX' then 'xx'
when (c.ID='AA' and c.STATE not in('KY')) then 'AA' end as Type
, sum(product_ind) as product
from line_item a 
join info c
on a.Dw=c.DW
where 1=1
group by a.line, case when c.ID='XX' then 'xx'
when (c.ID='AA' and c.STATE not in('KY')) then 'AA' end) a
where 1=1
and a.product>0
group by a.type
```

vs.

Code #2: Sub Query with Where Clause in Main Clause

```
select Type,sum(a.product)                                  
from 
(select a.line, c.id, c.state
from line_item a 
join info c
 on a.Dw=c.DW
where 1=1
group by a.line,c.id,c.state)a
where 1=1
and a.product>0
and a.ID='AA' 
and a.STATE not in('KY') 
group by a.type
```

Comment: And the difference is?.... And your second query actually runs? I didn't know its possible in oracle to not specify all columns of the select in the `group by` clause.

Comment: A 1% difference is not anything to really consider.  The performance for exactly the same query can differ from run to run.

Comment: When you say you get a slight difference, I'm assuming you mean you get different results returned? If so, have you tried doing a union all between both queries? It's possible that data is changing between when you run each query, resulting in the difference.

Comment: The actual query had the group by fixed @sagi . The query is off of a static table. Given this would you still expect it to change?